# Porque no puedo crear la llave foranea en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla con estos campos llamada NIVEL_PRECIO:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y tengo otra tabla con estos campos llamada NIVELPRECIO_USUARIO:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy queriendo agregar una llave foranea con esta sentencia:

```
ALTER TABLE [NIVELPRECIO_USUARIO]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([NIVEL_PRECIO])
REFERENCES [NIVEL_PRECIO] ([NIVEL_PRECIO])
GO
```

pero me da este error:

**Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 52
There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'NIVEL_PRECIO' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK__NIVELPREC__NIVEL__716F5931'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 52
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.**

Comment: Esto pasa porque tienes 2 llaves primarias en Nivel_Precio, por lo que si necesitas crear llaves foraneas de esa tabla, debes crear ambas llaves en las demas relaciones

Answer (score 1):

Al crear una Primary Key compuesta por varias columnas, la manera de identificar a un registro utilizando esa clave, es por todas las columnas que la forman.

El error te dice que no puede identificar una fila única por esa referencia, porque no es  clave primaria o candidata. Por tanto no puede referenciar con lo que le indicas a una sola fila.

```
CREATE TABLE NIVEL_PRECIO (
NIVEL_PRECIO VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
MONEDA VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
ID TINYINT,
PRIMARY KEY (NIVEL_PRECIO, MONEDA)
)
GO
INSERT INTO NIVEL_PRECIO 
(NIVEL_PRECIO, MONEDA, ID)
VALUES
('A','A',1),
('B','A',2),
('A','B',3);
GO
CREATE TABLE NIVELPRECIO_USUARIO
(USUARIO VARCHAR(25),
NIVEL_PRECIO VARCHAR(12),
NoteExistsFlaq tinyint NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (USUARIO, NIVEL_PRECIO)
)
GO

INSERT INTO NIVELPRECIO_USUARIO
(USUARIO, NIVEL_PRECIO, NoteExistsFlaq)
VALUES
('Luisa','A',0);
GO
```

Ahora con estos datos insertados, la fila correspondiente a Luisa, puede apuntar a los registros de nivel_precio cuyo id es 1 o 3.

Esto no es posible. Por tanto si necesitas relacionar NivelPrecio_usuario con Nivel_precio

```
DELETE FROM NIVELPRECIO_USUARIO WHERE USUARIO = 'Luisa'
-- Se podría añadir la constraint con NOCHECK
GO
ALTER TABLE NIVELPRECIO_USUARIO
ADD MONEDA VARCHAR(1)
GO
ALTER TABLE NIVELPRECIO_USUARIO  WITH CHECK 
ADD FOREIGN KEY(NIVEL_PRECIO, MONEDA)
REFERENCES NIVEL_PRECIO (NIVEL_PRECIO, MONEDA)
GO
INSERT INTO NIVELPRECIO_USUARIO
(USUARIO, NIVEL_PRECIO, NoteExistsFlaq, MONEDA)
VALUES
('Luisa','A',0,'A');
```

Ahora el motor ya puede saber que esta inserción de NivelPrecio_usuario se refiere al registro identificado en el ejemplo por el Id=1, porque la combinación de (Usuario, Moneda) accede a un registro único.

Answer (score 0):

Para crear la llave foránea debes apuntarla a una llave de la table referida. Cualquier llave, ya sea primaria o restricción única.

En tu intento, eso no es así, dado que la columna entre paréntesis en:

```
`REFERENCES [NIVEL_PRECIO] ([NIVEL_PRECIO])`
```

No es una llave de la table referida. La única llave es `(NIVEL_PRECIO, MONEDA)`, que es la PK.